# Using commands in Bash Script Variables

Tags: linux, bash, dropbox

I have a bash script which checks the current status of Dropbox

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
    echo Dropbox Status: 
    ~/bin/dropbox.py status
    sleep 1
    clear
done
```

This produces a output which can look like this.

```
Dropbox Status: 
Up to date
```

However I would like it to look like  this. So it is all on one line

```
Dropbox Status: Update
```

I have tried scripts such as

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
    STATUS=~/bin/dropbox.py status
    echo Dropbox Status: $STATUS
    sleep 1
    clear
done
```

However this just creates errors such as `Dropbox Status.sh: status: not found`

Is there a way to do what I am after?

Also if it is blatantly obvious I apologize since I am new to `Bash Script`

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `printf` and [command substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html):

```
printf "Dropbox Status: %s\n" "$(~/bin/dropbox.py status)"
```

or with intermediate variable:

```
status=$(~/bin/dropbox.py status)
printf "Dropbox Status: %s\n" "$status"
```

Also remember to quote your variables or they will undergo [word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting)

Why doesn't `STATUS=~/bin/dropbox.py status` work? Whats happens is that the command `status` is called with the environment variable `STATUS` set to `~/bin/dropbox.py`, sort of the same as running:

```
_status=$STATUS
export STATUS=~/bin/dropbox.py
status
export STATUS=_status
```

But without all the temporary variables

Answer (score 1):

You need to store result of command in your status var

```
  STATUS=$(~/bin/dropbox.py status)
```